How can I have multiple forks in the same github tree?
I have a situation where I have a Github tree where I want to work on two downstream, divergent branches of the same over all project. However, because the two downstreams are technically related, I can only fork one in total for the entire project and attempting to create more gets me the error of "No available destinations to fork this repository."
To elaborate more;
There is Master Source A. It is run by team A; we don't talk to them.
Fork B is another project that works downstream, doing it's own divergent thing with Source A as the base. In the perfect world it'd be its own repo, but that's not up to me. I have done work here and operate a fork from B, and wish to *continue *to do so.
Fork C is another project that works downstream like B, using Source A as the base. It is relatively divergent from both A and B. I wish to be able to push commits and work on Fork C, but because I have work on B, I cannot make a second fork from Fork C.
How could I go about having a fork from both B and C running at the same time or, failing that, be able to push commits to either fork B and C? Keep in mind that the three are all divergent work communities and I do not have a say in their organization, so nothing can really be modified.

If you mean like having a local repo where you can interact with fork b and c (on top of the local work), you can have more than a single remote setup on a local. Check git help remote.

Could it be that you need to rename your existing fork first?

You can fork A on GitHub, and you can have all of A, B, C, and your GitHub fork as remote in your local Git repo. You can open pull requests from your fork to any of A, B, C.
